Poincare section using Hamiltonian formalism
I'm trying to plot Poincaré surface of sections, using Hamiltonian formalism, for a system with 3 degrees of freedom. I have written a code for this. The code provides results for the integration of motion, but it does not generate the data points needed to plot the Poincaré surface of section. I'm trying to plot the Fig 1 and Fig 2 from the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.09171
I'm pasting my code below, can anyone please help me? Why I'm not getting the points?
Can one use the same technique for generating the data points for plotting 4D Poincare sections as for plotting 2D Poincare sections. In 4D Poincare sections, one can use r, pr pθ for the 3D projection, while pϕ can be represented by the color.
n = 4; M = 1; m = 1; 
SIGMA[r_, \[Theta]_] := r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2; 
BT2[r_] := r^2 + aa^2; TR[r_, \[Theta]_] := BT2[r] - 2 M r ;
Lambda[r_, \[Theta]_] := 
  BT2[r]^2 - aa^2 TR[r, \[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]]^2;
 gtt[r_, \[Theta]_] := -(1 - (2 M r)/SIGMA[r, \[Theta]]); 
gt\[Phi][r_, \[Theta]_] := -(( 2 r M aa Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/ 
  SIGMA[r, \[Theta]]);
g\[Phi]\[Phi][r_, \[Theta]_] := (Lambda[r, \[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/
 SIGMA[r, \[Theta]]; 
grr[r_, \[Theta]_] := SIGMA[r, \[Theta]]/TR[r, \[Theta]]; 
g\[Theta]\[Theta][r_, \[Theta]_] := SIGMA[r, \[Theta]];
gUtt[r_, \[Theta]_] := 
 g\[Phi]\[Phi][r, \[Theta]]/(-gt\[Phi][r, \[Theta]]^2 + 
  gtt[r, \[Theta]] g\[Phi]\[Phi][r, \[Theta]]); 
gUt\[Phi][r_, \[Theta]_] := - 
  gt\[Phi][r, \[Theta]]/(-gt\[Phi][r, \[Theta]]^2 + 
  gtt[r, \[Theta]] g\[Phi]\[Phi][r, \[Theta]]);
gU\[Phi]\[Phi][r_, \[Theta]_] := 
 gtt[r, \[Theta]]/(-gt\[Phi][r, \[Theta]]^2 + 
  gtt[r, \[Theta]] g\[Phi]\[Phi][r, \[Theta]]); 
gUrr[r_, \[Theta]_] := 1/grr[r, \[Theta]]; 
gU\[Theta]\[Theta][r_, \[Theta]_] := 1/ g\[Theta]\[Theta][r, \[Theta]];
glo = FullSimplify[{ {gtt[r, \[Theta]], 0, 0, 
     gt\[Phi][r, \[Theta]]}, {0, grr[r, \[Theta]], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
     g\[Theta]\[Theta][r, \[Theta]], 0}, {gt\[Phi][r, \[Theta]], 0, 0,
      g\[Phi]\[Phi][r, \[Theta]]}}];
gup = FullSimplify[{ {gUtt[r, \[Theta]], 0, 0, 
     gUt\[Phi][r, \[Theta]]}, {0, gUrr[r, \[Theta]], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
     gU\[Theta]\[Theta][r, \[Theta]], 0}, {gUt\[Phi][r, \[Theta]], 0, 
     0, gU\[Phi]\[Phi][r, \[Theta]]}}];

Slo = {Sx, Sy, Sz}; Plo = {pr, p\[Theta], 
  p\[Phi]}; xUp = {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}; Slotau = {Sx[\[Tau]], 
  Sy[\[Tau]], 
  Sz[\[Tau]]}; xUpTau = {r[\[Tau]], \[Theta][\[Tau]], \
\[Phi][\[Tau]]}; PloTau = {pr[\[Tau]], p\[Theta][\[Tau]], 
  p\[Phi][\[Tau]]};
LCSddd = 
  Table[Subscript[\[Epsilon], i, j, 
    k] = -(1/2) (i - j) (i - k) (j - k), {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 
    3}];

Ham[r_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_, pr_, p\[Theta]_, p\[Phi]_, Sx_, Sy_, 
   Sz_] := 
  pr + Sqrt[(
   p\[Phi]^2 + r^2 + p\[Theta]^2 (aa^2 + (-2 + r) r) + 
    aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)/(r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)]/Sqrt[
   1 + (4 r (aa^2 + r^2))/((aa^2 + (-2 + r) r) (aa^2 + 2 r^2 + 
       aa^2 Cos[2 \[Theta]]))] + (
   2 aa r Sz)/((aa^2 + r^2)^2 - 
    aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2) + (
   p\[Phi] Sz Sqrt[(aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) (r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)]
     Csc[\[Theta]]^2 (-1 + (r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)/
      Sqrt[(aa^2 + r^2)^2 - 
       aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2]))/(
   Sqrt[(p\[Phi]^2 + r^2 + p\[Theta]^2 (aa^2 + (-2 + r) r) + 
     aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)/(
    r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)] ((aa^2 + r^2)^2 - 
      aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + 
         r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2)) + (Csc[\[Theta]]^2 ((aa^2 - 2 r + 
           r^2)^(3/2)
          Sin[\[Theta]]^2 (-((
            p\[Theta] (-1 + r + Sqrt[aa^2 - 2 r + r^2])^2 ((
               8 r)/(-1 + r + Sqrt[aa^2 - 2 r + r^2])^2 - (
               8 (1 + (-2 + 2 r)/(2 Sqrt[aa^2 - 2 r + r^2])) (r^2 + 
                  aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2))/(-1 + r + Sqrt[
                 aa^2 - 2 r + r^2])^3) (1 + Sqrt[(
               p\[Phi]^2 + r^2 + p\[Theta]^2 (aa^2 + (-2 + r) r) + 
                aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)/(
               r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)]))/(
            8 (r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2))) - (
           aa^2 pr Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]])/(
           r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2) + 
           1/(2 (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) (r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2))
             p\[Theta] Sqrt[(
            p\[Phi]^2 + r^2 + p\[Theta]^2 (aa^2 + (-2 + r) r) + 
             aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)/(
            r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)] ((aa^2 + r^2)^2 - 
              aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + 
                 r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2) (-(((aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) (r^2 + 
                  aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2) (4 r (aa^2 + r^2) - 
                  aa^2 (-2 + 2 r) Sin[\[Theta]]^2))/((aa^2 + r^2)^2 - 
                 aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2)^2) + (
              2 r (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2))/((aa^2 + r^2)^2 - 
               aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2) + ((-2 + 
                 2 r) (r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2))/((aa^2 + r^2)^2 - 
               aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + 
                  r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2))) (Sy Cos[\[Phi]] - 
           Sx Sin[\[Phi]]) + 
        p\[Phi] (-1 + r - Sqrt[aa^2 - 2 r + r^2]) (r^2 + 
           aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2) (1 + Sqrt[(
           p\[Phi]^2 + r^2 + p\[Theta]^2 (aa^2 + (-2 + r) r) + 
            aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)/(
           r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)]) Sin[\[Theta]] Sqrt[(
         aa^2 - 2 r + r^2)/((aa^2 + r^2)^2 - 
          aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + 
             r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2)] (-Sz Sin[\[Theta]] + 
           Cos[\[Theta]] (Sx Cos[\[Phi]] + Sy Sin[\[Phi]])) + 
        1/Sqrt[(aa^2 + r^2)^2 - 
          aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2]
          p\[Phi] (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) (r^2 + 
           aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2) (1 + 
           2 Sqrt[(p\[Phi]^2 + r^2 + p\[Theta]^2 (aa^2 + (-2 + r) r) +
              aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)/(
            r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)]) Sin[\[Theta]] (-((
            aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]] (Sz Cos[\[Theta]] + 
               Sx Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]] + 
               Sy Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]]))/(
            r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)) + 
           1/(2 Sqrt[
             aa^2 - 2 r + 
              r^2] (r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)) ((aa^2 + r^2)^2 - 
              aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + 
                 r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2) (-(((aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) (r^2 + 
                  aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2) (4 r (aa^2 + r^2) - 
                  aa^2 (-2 + 2 r) Sin[\[Theta]]^2))/((aa^2 + r^2)^2 - 
                 aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2)^2) + (
              2 r (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2))/((aa^2 + r^2)^2 - 
               aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2) + ((-2 + 
                 2 r) (r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2))/((aa^2 + r^2)^2 - 
               aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + 
                  r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2)) (Sz Sin[\[Theta]] - 
              Cos[\[Theta]] (Sx Cos[\[Phi]] + 
                 Sy Sin[\[Phi]])))))/((1 + Sqrt[(
        p\[Phi]^2 + r^2 + p\[Theta]^2 (aa^2 + (-2 + r) r) + 
         aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)/(
        r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)]) Sqrt[(aa^2 - 2 r + 
         r^2) (p\[Phi]^2 + r^2 + p\[Theta]^2 (aa^2 + (-2 + r) r) + 
         aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2) ((aa^2 + r^2)^2 - 
         aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + 
            r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2)]) + (Csc[\[Theta]]^2 Sqrt[((aa^2 + 
         r^2)^2 - aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/(
      aa^2 - 2 r + 
       r^2)] (-((
         2 aa r (4 r (aa^2 + r^2) - 
            aa^2 (-2 + 2 r) Sin[\[Theta]]^2))/((aa^2 + r^2)^2 - 
           aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2)^2) + (
        2 aa)/((aa^2 + r^2)^2 - 
         aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2)) ((
        p\[Theta] p\[Phi] (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) (r^2 + 
           aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2 (Sy Cos[\[Phi]] - 
           Sx Sin[\[Phi]]))/
        Sqrt[(aa^2 + r^2)^2 - 
         aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2] + (aa^2 - 2 r + 
           r^2) (r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2) Sqrt[(
         p\[Phi]^2 + r^2 + p\[Theta]^2 (aa^2 + (-2 + r) r) + 
          aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)/(
         r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)] (1 + Sqrt[(
           p\[Phi]^2 + r^2 + p\[Theta]^2 (aa^2 + (-2 + r) r) + 
            aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)/(
           r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)]) Sin[\[Theta]]^3 (Sz Sin[\
\[Theta]] - Cos[\[Theta]] (Sx Cos[\[Phi]] + Sy Sin[\[Phi]])) + (
        p\[Phi]^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) (r^2 + 
           aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)^2 Sin[\[Theta]] (Sz Sin[\[Theta]] - 
           Cos[\[Theta]] (Sx Cos[\[Phi]] + Sy Sin[\[Phi]])))/((aa^2 + 
           r^2)^2 - aa^2 (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2) + 
        pr (aa^2 - 2 r + r^2)^(3/2)
          Sin[\[Theta]]^3 (-p\[Theta] (Sz Cos[\[Theta]] + 
              Sx Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]] + 
              Sy Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]]) + 
           pr Sqrt[aa^2 - 2 r + 
             r^2] (-Sz Sin[\[Theta]] + 
              Cos[\[Theta]] (Sx Cos[\[Phi]] + 
                 Sy Sin[\[Phi]])))))/(2 (r^2 + 
        aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)^2 Sqrt[(
      p\[Phi]^2 + r^2 + p\[Theta]^2 (aa^2 + (-2 + r) r) + 
       aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)/(
      r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)] (1 + Sqrt[(
        p\[Phi]^2 + r^2 + p\[Theta]^2 (aa^2 + (-2 + r) r) + 
         aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)/(r^2 + aa^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)]));

EOM1 = Table[
   D[xUpTau[[i]], \[Tau]] == 
    D[Ham[r, \[Theta], \[Phi], pr, p\[Theta], p\[Phi], Sx, Sy, Sz], 
     Plo[[i]]], {i, 1, 3}];
EOM2 = Table[
  D[PloTau[[i]], \[Tau]] == - 
    D[Ham[r, \[Theta], \[Phi], pr, p\[Theta], p\[Phi], Sx, Sy, Sz], 
     xUp[[i]]], {i, 1, 3}]; EOM3 = Table[D[Slotau[[i]], \[Tau]] == \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(3\)]\ \(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 1\), \(3\)]\ \(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(l = 1\), \(3\)]\ 
      LCSddd[\([\)\(i, j, k\)\(]\)] D[
        Ham[r, \[Theta], \[Phi], pr, p\[Theta], p\[Phi], Sx, \ Sy, 
         Sz], \ Slo[\([\)\(j\)\(]\)]]\ gup[\([\)\(k, 
        l\)\(]\)]\ Slo[\([\)\(l\)\(]\)]\)\)\), {i, 1, 3}];
EOM = Flatten[
   Join[{EOM1, EOM2, EOM3} /. 
                    r -> r[\[Tau]] /. \[Theta] -> \[Theta][\[Tau]] /. \
\[Phi] -> \[Phi][\[Tau]] /. pr -> pr[\[Tau]] /. 
                  p\[Theta] -> p\[Theta][\[Tau]] /. 
                 p\[Phi] -> p\[Phi][\[Tau]] /. Sx -> Sx[\[Tau]] /. 
               Sy -> Sy[\[Tau]] /. Sz -> Sz[\[Tau]] /. 
             Derivative[1][r[\[Tau]]][\[Tau]] -> 
              Derivative[1][r][\[Tau]] /. 
            Derivative[1][\[Theta][\[Tau]]][\[Tau]] -> 
             Derivative[1][\[Theta]][\[Tau]] /. 
           Derivative[1][\[Phi][\[Tau]]][\[Tau]] -> 
            Derivative[1][\[Phi]][\[Tau]] /. 
          Derivative[1][pr[\[Tau]]][\[Tau]] -> 
           Derivative[1][pr][\[Tau]] /. 
         Derivative[1][p\[Theta][\[Tau]]][\[Tau]] -> 
          Derivative[1][p\[Theta]][\[Tau]] /. 
        Derivative[1][p\[Phi][\[Tau]]][\[Tau]] -> 
         Derivative[1][p\[Phi]][\[Tau]] /. 
       Derivative[1][Sx[\[Tau]]][\[Tau]] -> 
        Derivative[1][Sx][\[Tau]] /. 
      Derivative[1][Sy[\[Tau]]][\[Tau]] -> 
       Derivative[1][Sy][\[Tau]] /. 
     Derivative[1][Sz[\[Tau]]][\[Tau]] -> Derivative[1][Sz][\[Tau]]]];

Orbit[r0_, \[Theta]0_, SS_, LL_, H_, END_] := (
   Clear[pr0, p\[Theta]0, p\[Phi]0, Sz0, sol, p\[Theta]GR, pth];
    pr0 = 0; \[Phi]0 = 0; Sx0 = 0; Sy0 = 0; Sz0 = SS;
   p\[Phi]0 = LL - SS;
   
   p\[Theta]GR = 
    pth /. Select[
      Solve[Ham[r0, \[Theta]0, \[Phi]0, pr0, pth, p\[Phi]0, 0, 0, 0] ==
         H, pth], (pth /. #) > 0 &];
   p\[Theta]0 = 
    p\[Theta]0 /. 
     FindRoot[
      Ham[r0, \[Theta]0, \[Phi]0, pr0, p\[Theta]0, p\[Phi]0, Sx0, Sy0,
         Sz0] == H, {p\[Theta]0, p\[Theta]GR[[1]]}];
   
   INT1 = {r[0] == r0, \[Theta][0] == \[Theta]0, \[Phi][0] == \[Phi]0};
   INT2 = {pr[0] == pr0, p\[Theta][0] == p\[Theta]0, 
     p\[Phi][0] == p\[Phi]0};
   INT3 = {Sx[0] == Sx0, Sy[0] == Sy0, Sz[0] == Sz0};
   INT = Flatten[Join[{INT1, INT2, INT3}]];
   
   SetSystemOptions[
    "NDSolveOptions" -> "DefaultSolveTimeConstraint" -> 100.`];
   data = 
    Reap[NDSolve[
      Flatten[Join[{EOM, INT}]], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi], pr, p\[Theta], 
       p\[Phi], Sx, Sy, Sz}, {\[Tau], 0, 
       END}, {Method -> {"EventLocator", 
         "Event" -> {\[Theta][\[Tau]] - Pi/2}, 
         "EventAction" :> Sow[{r[\[Tau]], pr[\[Tau]]}], 
         "Method" -> {"FixedStep", 
           "Method" -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, 
             "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", 
               AccuracyGoal -> MachinePrecision, 
               PrecisionGoal -> MachinePrecision, 
               "IterationSafetyFactor" -> 1}}}, 
         StartingStepSize -> 0.1}}]]
   );

r0 = 7; \[Theta]0 = Pi/2; aa = 0; SS = 1; LL = 3; H = 0.95; END = 1000;
Orbit[r0, \[Theta]0, SS, LL, H, END]


